# BeanLocator has not been set for servlet context My_portlet when using Service builder (Liferay)

Tags: liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

Working on a MVC spring Liferay 6.2 portlet.
I have built a service xml file and built the project. It manages an entity (let's say MyEntity ).
When I call my addMyEntity(long id) method from my controller, an exception is thrown saying:
15:53:04,135 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-60][PortletBeanLocatorUtil:42] BeanLocator is null for servlet context My_portlet
com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set for servlet context My_portlet

It looks the portal cannot access to some beans resources.
My web.xml file includes the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

portlet-application-context.xml only includes these beans:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    </bean>
```

I think what the server is looking for are these beans that are stored in a portlet-spring.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" default-destroy-method="destroy" default-init-method="afterPropertiesSet" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="com.company.project.servicebuilder.dao.service.MyEntityLocalService" class="com.company.project.servicebuilder.dao.service.impl.MyEntityLocalServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="com.company.project.servicebuilder.dao.service.MyEntityService" class="com.company.project.servicebuilder.dao.service.impl.MyEntityServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="com.company.project.servicebuilder.dao.service.persistence.MyEntityPersistence" class="com.company.project.servicebuilder.dao.service.persistence.MyEntityPersistenceImpl" parent="basePersistence" />
</beans>
```

However, I see no reference to portlet-spring.xml in other files so I m afraid that these beans are never declared when the portlet is deployed.
Should it be referenced somewhere?

Any other suggestion than my hypothesis?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The message in the log file could be a bit misleading.

One possible condition when this message would occur: if using ServiceBuilder and the Liferay portlet plugin project name does not match the configured context root. If you trace the ServiceBuilder template logic for generating the ClpSerializer.java class and the runtime execution stack, you could make the connection. This is my experience in LR6.2 CE.

Try matching your context root (in Eclipse - right-click project name/Properties/Web Project Settings) and make it the same as your Liferay portlet project name - e.g. "test-portlet". Re-build your service and deploy it.

Post your degree of success.

This was my solution to the above issue, as I was importing existing projects and not paying attention to the project settings. After matching the two values I was able to deploy successfully and execute the portlet logic.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user "So Te" and to some wide research I solve this problem specifying pluginName in pom.xml in configuration tag and running service-builder again.

```
<configuration>
  <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
  <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
  <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
  <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
  <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
  <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
  <pluginName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</pluginName>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the portlet and deploy it again, normal this problems are errors on the deploy.

Comment: No luck with this and restarting the server did not make it either.

Comment: I can actualy see a reference to portlet-spring.xml into service.properties:
...
 spring.configs=\...
 WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/portlet-spring.xml,\...

Is it supposed to work considering that my portlet-spring.xml path is 
<project-name>/source/main/resources//META-INF/portlet-spring.xml

I do not have any WEB-INF/classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when building my JUnit tests cases. I was having this error because Mockito standalone doesn't support static calls. To solution it, I had to use [Mockito with PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito) in order to allow static calls.